# Как правильно составить запрос с Any()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Доброго времени суток!

Есть необходимость получить выборку постов из БД (использую Entity Framework).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать запрос на линк.

Суть: 
Есть таблица с подписками для пользователя, в ней может быть несколько строк значений.

```
List<TRM_Subscribers> userSubscribers =sdb.TRM_Subscribers.Where(x => x.UserID == 1).ToList();
```

Также есть сами посты: (по двум параметрам из userSubscribers я хочу сделать выборку: IDCategory;idObj ;)

```
postses = sdb.TRM_Posts.Where(x => x.IDCategory==1 || userSubscribers.Any(g => g.IDObj == x.idObj && g.IDCat == x.IDCategory)).ToList();
```

На меня компилятор ругается: *Unable to create a constant value of type 'Project.Models.TRM_Subscribers'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<TRM_Subscribers> userSubscribers =sdb.TRM_Subscribers.Where(x => x.UserID == 1).ToList();
```

замените на

```
var query=sdb.TRM_Subscribers.Where(x => x.UserID == 1);
List<TRM_Subscribers> userSubscribers =query.ToList();

postses = sdb.TRM_Posts.Where(x => x.IDCategory==1 || query.Any(g => g.IDObj == x.idObj && g.IDCat == x.IDCategory)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, проблема-то ясна: `userSubscribers` у вас не `IQueryable` (из-за `.ToList()`), а `IEnumerable`, так что LINQ-провайдер не может странслировать код `userSubscribers.Any(g => g.IDObj == x.idObj && g.IDCat == x.IDCategory)` в SQL-запрос. Может быть, достаточно будет избавиться от материализации?

Comment: Подскажите, каким образом это лучше реализовать? 
Явно привести userSubscribers в IQueryable через .AsQueryable() ?

Comment: @Виктор Матюхин: Я имел в виду так, как в ответе. Не уверен, сработает ли — попробуйте!